# Random Sample From Probability Distribution a certain number of times

Tags: python, numpy, math

Let's say I have a normal distribution, and I want to sample from it 1000 times and if the value is in the top 20th percentile, I want to add 1 to a counter.  What's the optimal solution for this?

I'm trying to solve this using numpy and can't figure out the math behind it.  Right now I have this but I feel like it could be done mathematically:

```
import numpy as np
s = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
sum([val for val in s if val > np.percentile(s, 80)])
```

Comment: Theoretic 20th percentile or experimental one?

Comment: Where are you having trouble with specifically? Do you have any code to show? This is more of a task than it is a question as it is right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the generated array (you can play with mean and standard deviation, they are the default ones):

```
mu = 0
std = 1
arr = np.random.normal(mu, std, 1000)
```

This gives you the number of items in the top 20 percentile:

```
arr[arr > np.percentile(arr, 80)].size
Out[30]: 200
```

Edit: Your code is also nice. But you don't want to sum the values, you want to count them. So whenever `val > np.percentile(s, 80)` you want to sum 1's:

```
sum([1 for val in s if val > np.percentile(s, 80)])
Out[35]: 200
```

This will be slower than numpy's methods though.

Comment: FYI: You can replace `arr = mu + std * np.random.randn(1000)` with `arr = np.random.normal(mu, std, 1000)`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser That's better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a normal distribution, I'll assume you know `mu` and `sigma`, otherwise this question requires some extra post-processing. You'll have a certain `Z=(X-mu)/sigma` for each element you take out. Your 20th percentile would be any `X` that makes `Z>0.842`.

You can do something like:

```
if Z_val(x, mu, sigma) > 0.842: counter+=1
```